# Google CodePro test cases not generating easymock objects automatically

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, mocking, easymock, codepro

I have google CodePro Analytix tool installed for Eclipse Helios, when I generate unit tests using code pro, it generates the unit tests , but doesn't generate mock objects of interface, or in general doesn't create mock object, I do have some errors in my project, but if that would have been a problem I don't see how it would generate unit tests in the first place.?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question. You put a question mark on the end of a statement?

Comment: well the question is why is codePro not generating mock objects the way it should?

Comment: (was a joke... note that my question has a '.' and my question .. oh nevermind...) With respect to the errors in your project, it's entirely possible that the tool (I've never used it) does what it can when it encounters errors rather than refusing to do anything. I'd start by resolving your errors which is good practice and probably prevents eclipse from building anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that this option is enabled?

Window > CodePro > JUnit > Mock Objects > Use mock objects in generated tests

Answer (score 0):

Window→Preferences→CodePro→JUnit→Mock Objects
Here's my settings. In my other Eclipse workspaces I usually have a lot of addition patterns. I mock everything accept POJOs (e.g., DTOs)
[image: Eclipse→Window→Preferences→CodePro→JUnit→Mock Objects]